# How to generate a random character string of length 8 in Netezza?

Tags: random, string, netezza

I am trying to generate a random character string of length 8 in Netezza, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with a hex string, you could do:

```
select to_hex(round(random() * 2^32 - 1)::BIGINT) AS randchars;
```

You could also write a [user-defined function](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.udf.doc/c_udf_user_defined_funcs.html?cp=SSULQD_7.1.0%2F11) if you want a very specific type of string. For this, you would need SSH access on the Netezza appliance and some basic knowledge of C++. It may be simpler for you to write these functions in Lua if you're not comfortable with C++ or if you don't have an account on the appliance, but this requires Netezza Analytics to be installed.